# What causes the CSS3 animation to not show

Tags: html, css

Works with the proper animation with partial CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/njxdx6w8/

With my entire CSS, the animation does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/njxdx6w8/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="section group brClear">
    <div class="col span_2_of_3 vertAlignT span_pad_left">
        <div class="serviceHolder" style="height: 20px;"><a target="_blank" href="letter.pdf" title="Winter 2013" class="setBold defaultLinks">Winter 2013 Newsletter</a></div>
        <div class="serviceHolder">STUFF GOES HERE</div>
        <div class="serviceHolder"><a title="Download Newsletter" href="letter.pdf" class="btn btn-1 btn-1e">Download</a><a title="Open Newsletter" target="_blank" href="letter.pdf" class="btn btn-1 btn-1e">Open</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used the developer tools for both Chrome and IE and can't seem to figure out which of my style is causing the issue.

Please help me resolve it.

Comment: Something is probably overwriting your animation.

Comment: You want us to do what you should do and debug your CSS? Start by removing chunks and narrow down where the problem starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White `background` property in the body tag couses the problem. Move your background property to a seperate `html` tag.

```
html { background: #FFF no-repeat center center fixed;}
```

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge your welcome. I edited my post for the right usage. Also I'll be glad if you mark as an answer if you really think it is.

Comment: Of course. I changed and it worked! I can accept it after 6 minutes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

in your **html, body{}** css take out
**background: #FFF no-repeat center center fixed;**